Issue with PiCamera Connectivity on Raspberry Pi
I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 and the PiCamera2 package to capture images. Initially, everything worked perfectly with my code.
However, I encountered the following issues:
The same code does not work on a Raspberry Pi 3. The code also stopped working on the Raspberry Pi 4 where it originally ran successfully. I have tried using different PiCamera packages, but only the PiCamera2 package worked on the Pi 4 (initially). On the Pi 3, it doesn’t work at all.
On the Raspberry Pi 4, I now see the following error: libcamera error Steps I’ve already taken:
Verified that the camera connection is secure. Updated and upgraded the Raspberry Pi OS. Reinstalled the PiCamera2 package.(Also Picamera not working on new bookworm OS) Tried using both the Bookworm and Buster versions of Raspberry Pi OS. I’m unsure if this is a compatibility issue, a library problem, or a hardware issue. Any guidance on resolving this issue or ensuring compatibility between PiCamera2 and Raspberry Pi models would be greatly appreciated.
Setup Details:
Raspberry Pi 4 and Raspberry Pi 3 Camera: PiCamera module Library: PiCamera2 OS: Bookworm and Buster Thanks in advance for your help!

You might be able to get an answer to your question in the updated official camera manual that was released the other day

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?
